# Good and effective CSV/TSV Reader for Java

Tags: java, csv, large-files, opencsv

I am trying to read big `CSV` and `TSV` (tab-separated) Files with about `1000000` rows or more. Now I tried to read a `TSV` containing `~2500000` lines with [`opencsv`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), but it throws me an `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It works with smaller `TSV` Files with `~250000` lines. So I was wondering if there are any other `Libraries` that support the reading of huge `CSV` and `TSV` Files. Do you have any ideas?

Everybody who is interested in my Code (I shorten it, so `Try-Catch` is obviously invalid):

```
InputStreamReader in = null;
CSVReader reader = null;
try {
    in = this.replaceBackSlashes();
    reader = new CSVReader(in, this.seperator, '\"', this.offset);
    ret = reader.readAll();
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } 
}
```

Edit: This is the Method where I construct the `InputStreamReader`:

```
private InputStreamReader replaceBackSlashes() throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(this.csvFile);
            in = new Scanner(fis, this.encoding);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String nextLine = in.nextLine().replace("\\", "/");
                // nextLine = nextLine.replaceAll(" ", "");
                nextLine = nextLine.replaceAll("'", "");
                out.write(nextLine.getBytes());
                out.write("\n".getBytes());
            }

            return new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            in.close();
            fis.close();
            this.logger.error("Problem at replaceBackSlashes", e);
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you read it yourself thanks to a BufferedReader?

Comment: Actually I wanted have nicely crafted ,common used Code and I don't want to reinvent the wheel, actually that's the reason everybody is using libs I think. But if there isn't anything working, I will do so.

Comment: with that many rows I would look into processing the file in batches: Read n lines from the file, process with csv, read next batch etc.

Comment: @opi Well this could be a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not tried it, but I had investigated superCSV earlier.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/supercsv/

http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/

Check if that works for you, 2.5 million lines.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at this lib.

Comment: Thank you. `supercsv` handles `2 500 000` lines pretty nice.

Comment: @Robin As a Super CSV developer I'm glad to hear this, though to be fair to opencsv, you're bound to run into (memory) issues if you use `reader.readAll()` instead of reading each line and doing something with it. Your `replaceBackslashes()` method could also run into issues as you're writing the whole file to memory. Was your NPE occuring when closing one of your streams/readers?

Comment: @HoundDog Now that I am switching from openCsv to superCsv, I am quite happy with my decision, because superCsv seems to be very well documented and widely used, so I think it was the right decision. What would be your recommendation to my `replaceBackslashes()`? Yes the NPE occured when I tried to close the reader.

Comment: does supercsv support tsv files too?

Comment: CSVListReader breaks for tsv if it has ' or " , any work changes needed

Answer (score 17):

Do not use a CSV parser to parse TSV inputs. It will break if the TSV has fields with a quote character, for example.

[uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) comes with a TSV parser. You can parse a billion rows without problems.

Example to parse a TSV input:

```
TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings();
TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);

// parses all rows in one go.
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(yourFile));
```

If your input is so big it can't be kept in memory, do this:

```
TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings();

// all rows parsed from your input will be sent to this processor
ObjectRowProcessor rowProcessor = new ObjectRowProcessor() {
    @Override
    public void rowProcessed(Object[] row, ParsingContext context) {
        //here is the row. Let's just print it.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
};
// the ObjectRowProcessor supports conversions from String to whatever you need:
// converts values in columns 2 and 5 to BigDecimal
rowProcessor.convertIndexes(Conversions.toBigDecimal()).set(2, 5);

// converts the values in columns "Description" and "Model". Applies trim and to lowercase to the values in these columns.
rowProcessor.convertFields(Conversions.trim(), Conversions.toLowerCase()).set("Description", "Model");

//configures to use the RowProcessor
settings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);

TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);
//parses everything. All rows will be pumped into your RowProcessor.
parser.parse(new FileReader(yourFile));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: You have not done settings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);

Answer (score 1):

Try switching libraries as suggested by `Satish`. If that doesn't help, you have to split the whole file into tokens and process them.

Thinking that your `CSV` didn't had any escape characters for commas

```
// r is the BufferedReader pointed at your file
String line;
StringBuilder file = new StringBuilder();
// load each line and append it to file.
while ((line=r.readLine())!=null){
    file.append(line);
}
// Make them to an array
String[] tokens = file.toString().split(",");
```

Then you can process it. Don't forget to trim the token before using it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that question is still active but here is the one I use successfully. Still may have to implement more interfaces such as Stream or Iterable, however:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

/** Reader for the tab separated values format (a basic table format without escapings or anything where the rows are separated by tabulators).**/
public class TSVReader implements Closeable 
{
    final Scanner in;
    String peekLine = null;

    public TSVReader(InputStream stream) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        in = new Scanner(stream);
    }

    /**Constructs a new TSVReader which produces values scanned from the specified input stream.*/
    public TSVReader(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {in = new Scanner(f);}

    public boolean hasNextTokens()
    {
        if(peekLine!=null) return true;
        if(!in.hasNextLine()) {return false;}
        String line = in.nextLine().trim();
        if(line.isEmpty())  {return hasNextTokens();}
        this.peekLine = line;       
        return true;        
    }

    public String[] nextTokens()
    {
        if(!hasNextTokens()) return null;       
        String[] tokens = peekLine.split("[\\s\t]+");
//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
        peekLine=null;      
        return tokens;
    }

    @Override public void close() throws IOException {in.close();}
}
```

Comment: Actually I am pretty satisfied with SuperCSV. However thanks for a natural implementation.